# How to remove indentation highlighting in vim?

Tags: vim, configuration, syntax-highlighting, indentation

As I use vim, it tries to be helpful by highlighting groups of four spaces in yellow, as shown.

[image: Example of the highlighting in question]

My `.vimrc` file says, in its entirety, `set tabstop=4`.

How can I keep vim from highlighting the indentation in my files?

Comment: maybe you have a plugin installed? ~/.vim/plugin/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is this a case of highlighting the last search? If so, try typing ":noh".

Comment: That could still be it.  If the `h` setting isn't in the `'viminfo'` option, Vim may highlight the string stored in the `/` register when loading the viminfo file.

Comment: As it turns out, that was it.  I didn't realize that searches were persistent.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If [bentsai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851094/how-to-remove-indentation-highlighting-in-vim/2851142#2851142)'s answer isn't correct, then there's probably a [match pattern](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#:match) in effect.  In that case, `:call clearmatches()` will remove the highlighting.

Answer (score 7):

Also, :set list will cause the tabs to get NonText highlighting, which might be yellow background.
In that case, :set nolist will remove the coloring.