# How to remove indentation highlighting with yellow color in vim?

Tags: vim

[image]

Need to remove yellow col
[image]

or highlights (for tabs & spaces) from file for vim.

Comment: Open Vim, and search random characters like "asadadas", the highlighted spaces should not longer be highlighted then. Probably, in previous session you searched for spaces and that's why it's shown as highlighted.

Comment: I have run the command vim with random character but still I am facing same issue for space, its getting highlighted with yellow color.

Comment: Yes. It is helping me to remove the color highlighted for spaces.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851094/how-to-remove-indentation-highlighting-in-vim

Comment: Use the command `:noh` (`:nohlsearch`) to cancel current highlighting